# Rearrange hexadecimal string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to rearrange characters in a string representation of a hexadecimal number. Here's an example of an input (upper string) and the desired result (lower string).
[image]

I've borrowed code from this guy here:
http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.hr/2009/05/converting-decimal-to-hexadecimal-with.html
Thanks, guy! That should take care of dec-to-hex conversion for me, and it works, I've tested it.

Now here's my T-SQL code that should handle the moving around the parts part:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DecodeDecKeyCard
(
    @value AS BIGINT
) RETURNS CHAR(8) AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @convertedNum VARCHAR(MAX),
            @result CHAR(8) = '',
            @flag INT = 1,
            @loop INT = 4;
    SELECT @convertedNum = dbo.ConvertToBase(@value, 16);
    WHILE @loop > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @result = @result + SUBSTRING(@convertedNum, (@loop*2) - @flag, 1);
            IF(@flag = 1)
                SET @flag = 0;
            ELSE
                SET @flag = 1;
                SET @loop = @loop -1;
        END
    RETURN @result
END
```

Since I am a complete noob when it comes to SQL, I don't know how to debug this. I've googled some stuff about it, but the results keep referring me to payed versions of VS and some hacks or whatnot... To be completely frank, I'm scarce on time (and money) to be setting this up by myself at the moment.

Some things related to the above code:

- I know I will always receive a 10 digit decimal number as a parameter
- I know it will always result in an 8 digit hex number
- dbo.ConvertToBase is the aforementioned 'borrowed' function

EDIT:
The code I have at the moment results in no data getting returned... The hex number is treated as a string from the start.

I would like it pointed out why my code does not work?

Comment: So your function doesn't work as you expect? You said you get a 10 digit input but show an 8 digit input. did you just drop the 0x?

Comment: The hex number is never treated as an INT, so I guess 0x is unnecessary. I'll edit the question so it's clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured out what you meant. The argument the function receives is a 10 digit long number. **That number then is transformed into an 8 digit hex number, represented as a string**. And then that number gets rearranged in the manner as shown in the pic.

Comment: The `@flag` shell game seems like an excessively complicated way of trying to take pairs of characters. Why not just grab two at a time and let `@loop` move along?

Comment: Then it seems like all you need to do is set @result = `RIGHT(@result,2) + SUBSTRING(@result,5,2) + SUBSTRING(@result,3,2) + LEFT(@result,2)`  in your function before returning @result.... as listed below...

Answer (score 3):

Binary style:

```
declare @value         int       = 1234567890
declare @value_bytes   binary(4) = cast(@value as binary(4))
declare @swapped_bytes binary(4) = cast(reverse(@value_bytes) as binary(4))

select 
    @value_bytes   [Input],
    @swapped_bytes [Output], 
    convert(char(8), @swapped_bytes, 2) [As text]
```

For:

```
Input       Output      As text
0x499602D2  0xD2029649  D2029649
```

UDF:

```
create function DecodeDecKeyCard ( @value as int ) returns char(8)
as 
begin 
    return convert(char(8), cast(reverse(cast(@value as binary(4))) as binary(4)), 2)
end
```

(This expects the value to not exceed the max for a 32bit integer, if it can use `bigint`, `binary(8)` and `char(16)`)

Comment: You have a return and variable declared as `char` which is a *single* character as you have no size (`char(8)`), added UDF above.

Answer (score 1):

```
--10 CHARACTER INPUT
declare @input varchar(10) = '0xD2CF901A'

SELECT RIGHT(RIGHT(@input,8),2) + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@input,8),5,2) + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@input,8),3,2) + LEFT(RIGHT(@input,8),2)

--8 CHARACTER INPUT
declare @input varchar(10) = 'D2CF901A'

SELECT RIGHT(@input,2) + SUBSTRING(@input,5,2) + SUBSTRING(@input,3,2) + LEFT(@input,2)
```